# How to form multiple get requests within a single rest api?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have the following get requests in my code:

```
@GetMapping
public ArrayList<Response> getGeneralResponses() {
        return requestService.getGeneralResponses();
}

@GetMapping
public ArrayList<Response> getWinningResponses() {
        return requestService.getWinningResponses();
}
```

How can i make get calls that only activate one of these methods? For example,i want to make a get call that only activates the "getWinningResponses()" method. I'm using postman for testing.

Please explain it simply, i'm very,very new at spring and api's in general.

Comment: why dont u write a third method with '@GetMapping , based on ur URL path i.e '@pathParam or '@QueryParam u can call the selective method i.e. getGeneralResponses or  getWinningResponses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very ordinary simplification (I'd very much recommend a tutorial [eg. Baeldung], not to mention reading the official docs):

you specify an endpoint (a path to your exposed resources) within a class annotation and/or a method annotation:

```
@Controller("/path1")
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/path2")
    public String getAnother() {
        return "Another";
    }
}
```

This way, if you're app is running on port `8080`, after visiting `http://localhost:8080/path1` you'll see `Hello` and after `http://localhost:8080/path1/path2` - `Another`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for your help! I understand the idea.